# Access Database - Most Recent Record - Max Function - Expanding Inner Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, max

I'm in the process of building a database to keep track of loaning machinery. Thanks to a very helpful user, I've been able to get an SQL query that spits out the latest statuses of each machine.

What I now need is to be able to interact with those results in such a way as to allow me to search these results for the following details:

All machines currently loaned
Only available machines of a specific make (to be chosen from a list by the user) 
I will probably need more, but I'm hoping that with working queries for the above I can piece together anything else I might need.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Current SQL query that picks out the latest movement records is:

```
SELECT t.serial, t.EntryDateMovements, t.location, t.status
FROM movements AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT Movements.Serial, Max(Movements.EntryDateMovements) AS MaxOfEntryDateMovements
            FROM Movements
            GROUP BY Movements.Serial)  AS MaxMovements
    ON  (t.serial = MaxMovements.serial)
    AND (t.EntryDateMovements = MaxMovements.MaxOfEntryDateMovements);
```

Two relevant tables are:

Movements

- MovementID (PK - Autonumber)
- EntryDateMovement (Automatically entered via form use)
- EntryTime Movement (Automatically entered via form use)
- Serial (FK - Stock Table)
- Location (Limited to combobox list of values when entered via form (Customer, Headoffice, warehouse, etc))
- LocationDetail (Not restricted)
- Status (Limited to combobox list of values when entered via form (available, booked, repair etc))

Stock

- Serial (PK manual entered via form)
- Category (Limited to combobox list of values when entered via form (Drill, Saw, Kit etc))
- Make (Limited to combobox list of values when entered via form (Dewalt, BlackDecker, Silverline etc)_
- Model (Limited to combobox list of values when entered via form (S2300, WA1500 etc booked, repair etc))
- Capacity (Limited to combobox list of values when entered via form (1L, 2L, 3L etc, only used with some records))
- Type (Limited to combobox list of values when entered via form (Automatic, manual, etc, only used with some records))

Comment: have you tried anything?  this should not be a 'do it for me' site.

Comment: This is a "I don't even know where to start" kind of thing. I've muddled through the rest of the database, which is complete and ready to go, this is the last hurdle, and it is above my knowledge level. Even a link to a learning resource tackling this issue would give me enough to move on. I think you might be confusing my lack of knowledge with laziness, they are not the same thing.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: That is much appreciated, I will take a look.